# Why puts File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))) give me different results?

Tags: ruby

*using ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32] on Win7*

In a directory (`d:\download\ruby` to be exact) I have two files - calling.rb and called.rb

**calling.rb**

```
require_relative 'called'
print_path()
```

**called.rb**

```
def print_path()
  puts "File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) is #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}"
  puts "File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))) is #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)))}"
  puts File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
print_path()
```

Could someone explain why when executing directly called.rb gives me

```
d:\download\ruby>ruby called.rb
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) is d:/download/ruby
File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))) is d:/download/ruby
d:/download/ruby
```

different result as when using the same code from calling.rb?

```
d:\download\ruby>ruby calling.rb
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) is d:/download/ruby
File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))) is d:/download
d:/download/ruby
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) is d:/download/ruby
File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))) is d:/download
d:/download/ruby

d:\download\ruby>
```

Comment: @vgoff, is see nothing wrong here, the only place Radek uses slashes is in his prompt and in his explanation where he shows the path where the files are run and on a windows machine that is correct

Comment: the output from Ruby puts \___FILE\___ are forward slashes in every OS, welcome to the windows world of headaches 8>)

Comment: The command line prompts are clearer now and separates the output a little more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `__FILE__` is the current source file name, and 'current' is the keyword here.

You are also getting the Directory name of a directory in your nesting.

To troubleshoot this, perhaps the following puts lines will help:

```
def print_path()
  puts "File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) is #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}"
  puts "File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))) is #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)))}"
  puts File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
```

Comment: To trace when the `__FILE__` value changes, you can place some puts lines in both files.  You will then see what the current file is, and how it is represented by the `__FILE__` variable.

Comment: could  you suggest where and what to use to debug? I'd say that the `puts` I used is good enough to see what is happening.

Comment: My example has the non-nested as the last line, but shows both ways in the troubleshooting puts lines above it.

Comment: got it. I copied the code from somewhere and either nested it by mistake or it was like that. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: But the nesting doesn't explain why, when executing the called.rb directly I get the same path in all 3 lines. - I updated my question. I used your debugging lines and added the results from that.

Comment: yes, that's what's happening to me. I am using *ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32] on Win7* if it matters...

Comment: I really don't understand :-) how can we both get different results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87060/discussion-between-vgoff-and-radek).

Answer (score 0):

You have done it everything perfectly and the results are also correct. The only noticeable thing here is,

1. When you execute `called.rb`, the print_path() executed only one time
2. But when you execute `calling.rb`, the print_path() executed twice. Because you required the whole file **called.rb** in **calling.rb**. So first, *called.rb* file's **print_path()** method is executed and then the *calling.rb* file's **print_path()** method executed again.

**That's why you received the same result twice**. Regarding the same result case, you placed both files in same directory. That's why your results also same in both `print_path()` execution.

You will get the different results if you place anyone of the above file under different directory.